# javascript recursively link objects to build an object tree

Tags: javascript

I have two objects that look like this:

```
var cache = {
 '39' : { id : 39, name : 'Tom' },
 '40' : { id : 40, name : 'David'},
 '41' : { id : 41, name : 'Daniel'},
 '356': { id :356, grp: 'ROM', fee: '$35'} 
}

var tree = {
 person : { id : 39 },
 memberships : { id : 356 },
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to write a recursive function that will take the `tree` object as an argument and generate a data structure that references/links to the corresponding object in the `cache` object. So finally I must be able to access user 'Tom' like this: `tree.person.name`.

I'm using recursion for two reasons:

1. My actual `tree` object is way more complicated than what I have shown here (it is nested)
2. It varies depending on the user input and the depth of the tree is unknown

I wrote this recursive function to do the referencing/linking:

```
var traverse = function (jsonObj) {
    if( typeof jsonObj == "object" ) { 
        if(cache[jsonObj.id]){
          jsonObj = Ocache[jsonObj.id];

      }
      $.each(jsonObj, function(k, v) {
        traverse(v);
      });
    }
    else {
        // jsonObj is a number or string
    }
  }
```

Then I call the function like

```
   traverse(tree);
```

but when I use the debugger to see my `tree` object, nothing has changed: `tree` is the same as before. How do I achieve this and reference/link objects in the cache object?

Comment: Can you post desired result, also `$.each()` is jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your code is `jsonObj = cache[jsonObj.id]`: Here you're overwriting `jsonObj`, a local variable in `traverse`, which has no effect on anything outside of this particular function call.

In order to make changes to the nested tree object itself, you have to keep track of the parent object and the current key:

```js
var cache = {
    '39' : { id: 39, name: 'Tom' },
    '40' : { id: 40, name: 'David'},
    '41' : { id: 41, name: 'Daniel'},
    '356': { id: 356, grp: 'ROM', fee: '$35'} 
};

var tree = {
    person: { id: 39 },
    memberships: { id: 356 },
};

function traverse(obj) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        var v = obj[k];
        if (!v || typeof v !== 'object') continue;
        if (cache[v.id]) {
            obj[k] = cache[v.id];
        } else {
            traverse(v);
        }
    }
}

traverse(tree);

console.log(tree);
```

I added the `!v` check because `typeof null` is `object`, but we don't want to recurse into `null`.

I did not fix that an object without an `id` is treated as having `id: 'undefined'` (if you don't want that, add an additional check to the `if (cache[v.id])` line).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. This works perfectly for the given tree object. But I just realized that there are arrays of objects in the 'tree' object. Like the following    

var tree = {
    person: { id: 39 },
    memberships: [ { id: 356 }, { id : 370} ], 
    contacts: { phonenumbers : [{ id : 150}, {id : 171}] }
};     

how do I extend the above solution for these kind of objects?